# Cannot import name get_date_formats - Django and Dotcloud Problems

Tags: django, dotcloud

I was cleaning my Documents folder and renamed the folder containing all the python/html files for the application. I edited an HTML file, pushed to dotcloud, and the application is down. Does anyone know a why to fix this? I've already tried renaming the folder containing the files back to the original and pushing to dotcloud, but it failed.

Edit 1: I just tried pushing with older files from a previous computer, and it also failed. (This solution usually works, so is there something at dotcloud's end that changed?)

My application is here: www.hours.lambertnhs.com

Comment: When you say you renamed the folder and re-pushed, what do you mean by "it failed"? Did the push fail? Or did the push succeed but your app is still down?

Comment: Push succeeded but app is still down. I was able to change the admin.py for the Chronograph for the initial error to disappear (pushed, traceback on website error message.) However, a new error appeared: no such table: django_session. I was told elsewhere that this is a compatibility issue.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new temporary instance and pushing to that just to see if it works?